# Derivatives and tangent to the line of a curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equations of all tangent lines to the curve y=x/(x+1) that intersect the point (1,2). Note that the point (1,2) does not lie on the curve. Please simplify your final answer as much as possible.

This is what I have done so far. I don't know if it is correct.

1/(x+1)= -x-2/(x-1) [cross-multiplied] to get, x-1=-x^2 -3x -2

I made it equal to zero to get a quadratic equation of x^2 + 4x + 1 = 0 to solve for x
I got x = -2 +- root 3

I dont know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Pick some point $(a,b)$ which lies on the curve $y=\frac{x}{x+1}$.  This means that $b=\frac{a}{a+1}$.  Taking the derivative using the quotient rule, we find:

$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

so the slope of the tangent line at our point $(a,b)$ is

$$y'(a)=\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}$$

The point slope formula then tells us that the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(a,b)$ is

$$y-b=\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}(x-a)$$

We want the point $(1,2)$ to satisfy this equation, so remembering that $b=\frac{a}{a+1}$, we have:

$$2-b=2-\frac{a}{a+1}=\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}(1-a)$$

This equation reduces to the quadratic $a^2+4a+1=0$ (which is the quadratic you found).  The solutions $a=-2\pm\sqrt{3}$ can be plugged back into the equation

$$y=\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}(x-a)+\frac{a}{1+a}=\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}x+\frac{a^2}{(1+a)^2}$$

to obtain the equations of the desired tangent lines.

Here is a helpful picture plotted with Wolfram|Alpha:
[image]

Notice where the tangent lines intersect!

Comment: So the quadratic that I found with the solutions for a is correct?

Comment: @LisaPaima: Yes.  Although I'm not exactly sure how you found it, but it is the correct answer.

Comment: Oh okay good, thank you. One more question; when I am substituting a into the formula to give me the equations for the tangent lines, do I have to substitute any values for x?

Comment: @LisaPaima: Great question.  The equation of a line represents infinitely many points, and thus when writing the equation of a line, we should keep $x$ as a variable.  Plugging in a constant value for $x$ will specify a particular point on the line, and thus not represent the entire line.

Comment: I substituted 'a' into the equation, and for one of my a values I got: -0.25x + 1.366025404 .. It's not meant to be in decimals. I'm not sure if this is correct..

Comment: @LisaPaima: If you look at my picture, you'll see that both tangent lines have positive slope, so I'm not sure how you got your line.  The exact expressions for the tangent lines are given in the picture, next to the purple and gold hash marks in the key.

Comment: Would this be correct   y= 2 + (7-4*sqrt3)(x-1) and my second equation y= 2 + (7+4*sqrt3)(x-1)